# How much weight do I need to lose to grab the basketball rim?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile, estimation, biology

I am 195 pounds, 71" tall, standing reach of 92”.

Currently, I can jump to touch 115" in height (finger tips).

I'd like to jump to 123" in. to grab the basketball rim. (Note: 10ft/120" is the height of the basketball rim.)

Assuming that I maintain the same jumping power, how much weight/mass do I need to lose in order to jump to 123" in.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a conversion to SI for my own benefit: 195 lbm is 88.5 kg, 5' 11" is 1.8 m, 115" is 2.9 m, and 123" is 3.1 m.

You can therefore jump a total of 2.9 m - 1.8 m = 1.1 m. Raising an object of mass 88.5 kg a distance 1.1 m in Earth's gravitational field of strength 9.8 N/kg requires an energy $$V=mgh=88.5~\mathrm{kg}\times9.8~\mathrm{N\,kg^{-1}}\times1.1~\mathrm{m}= 954~\mathrm{J}$$ We can use this "jump energy" to calculate the maximum mass you could have in order to jump your requested 3.1 m - 1.8 m = 1.3 m: $$m=\frac{V}{gh}=\frac{954~\mathrm{J}}{9.8~\mathrm{N}\,\mathrm{kg}^{-1}\times1.3~\mathrm{m}}=74.9~\mathrm{kg}$$Which implies you must lose 88.5 kg - 74.9 kg = 13.6 kg, which is almost exactly 30 lbm.

Generally, if you assume energy conservation, you could calculate your necessary massloss $\Delta m$ as follows: $$\Delta m=m_0\left(1-\frac{h_0}{h}\right)$$where $h_0$ is the highest you can jump at some initial mass $m_0$ and $h$ is your target jump height.

Edit: to answer the question you asked in your comment — why does $mh=m_0h_0$ not apply here? Well, the simple answer is that it does! In fact, the general equation I gave you above is exactly the equation you gave, written in a different form. Here's the derivation, using energy equivalence as a starting point:

\begin{align*}
mgh&=m_0gh_0\\
mh&=m_0h_0\\
m&=m_0\frac{h_0}{h}\\
m_0-m&=m_0-m_0\frac{h_0}{h}\\
m_0-m&=m_0\left(1-\frac{h_0}{h}\right)\\
\implies \Delta m &= \boxed{m_0\left(1-\frac{h_0}{h}\right)}
\end{align*}

As you can see, totally equivalent.

Comment: As long as none of that weight is lost as leg muscle.

Comment: @Riley thanks so much for the answer. I'm trying to wrap my head on 2 things.

1) Why doesn't: 1ℎ1=2ℎ2 apply here? I'd like to lose less weight. :)

2) Why does the answer so much when I calculate using my arm reach of 92" / 2.34 m (vs. height). Technically I should've given arm reach, since that is how the jump is measured.

Comment: @Kenny I've answered your Q1 in an edit. As for Q2, I'm a little confused what you're asking but I'll try: For sake of easy numbers, let us say you are 2 m tall, and when you reach your arms straight up above you, at highest they are 3 m above the ground. You can jump a total of 1 m, but the hoop is 5 m above the ground. 5 m - (1 m + 3 m) = 1 m, so your jump is 1 m short. Add that to what you already jump, and your $h_0$ is 1 m, and $h$ will be 2 m.

Comment: @RileyScottJacob Thanks much! Sweet answer!